# Mouseover highlight label in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, labeling

I would like to see the geoJSON placemark label once hover it.

I found a few examples, but they refer mostly to providing a pop-up only:

[Showing popup on mouse-over, not on click using Leaflet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/showing-popup-on-mouse-over-not-on-click-using-leaflet)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408445/leaflet-mouseout-event-on-marker

[Show popup on marker hover / mouseover, hide on mouseout, and keep open on click](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271602/show-popup-on-marker-hover-mouseover-hide-on-mouseout-and-keep-open-on-click)

My code looks as follows:

```
  job = L.geoJson(data, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        feature.properties.myKey = '<b>'+ feature.properties.Owner + '</b>; ' + feature.properties.Address
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:6,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor(feature.properties.Contractor),
            fillColor:  getColor(feature.properties.Contractor),
            fillOpacity: 0.8

            });  //.bindTooltip(feature.properties.Name);
        },

            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.Owner;
                label = String(feature.properties.Owner)

            function highlightFeature(e){
                var ly = label
                }

                var popupContent = "<p><h2>" +
                feature.properties.Owner + "</h2><b> Number of units:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Units + "</br> <b>Client reference:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Client_Ref + "</br>" +
                '</br><center><a href="'+ feature.properties.Directory +'" target="_blank">Local directory</a></center></p>' +
                '<center><font color="red"><a href="'+ feature.properties.Sharepoint +'" target="_blank">Sharepoint</a></font></center></p>';

                if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
                }
                    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
                    layer.on({
            mouseover: function (e) {
                this.setStyle({
                    'fillColor': '#663300',
                    'weight':11,
                });
                highlightFeature(ly);
            },

            mouseout: function (e) {
                this.setStyle({
                    'fillColor': getColor(feature.properties.Contractor),
                    'weight': 2
                });
            }
            /*
            click: function () {
                // TODO Link to page
                alert('Clicked on ' + feature.properties.Title)
            }
            */
        });

            }

            }).addData(data).addTo(map);
```

where inside the  `mouseover: function (e) {` I plotted the `highligtfeature` function `highlightFeature(ly);`  as added to the `onEachFeature: function` above.
The map is fine, but I see no effect.
The console says:

> (index):497 Uncaught ReferenceError: ly is not defined
>       at NewClass.mouseover ((index):497)
>       at NewClass.fire (Events.js:190)
>       at NewClass._fireDOMEvent (Map.js:1386)
>       at NewClass._handleDOMEvent (Map.js:1343)
>       at HTMLDivElement.handler (DomEvent.js:79)

Shall I input the:

```
     .bindTooltip(label, {permanent: true, direction: "center", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip();
```

somewhere in the code too?

Could you help me with it?

I don't want popop opened, only the label.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be gained by the `.bindToolTip` option, whewre we must put `permanent: false`, if we want to have the name be hovered instead of visible permanently.

My code snippet now looks as follows:

Instead of:

```
   job = L.geoJson(data, {

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    feature.properties.myKey = '<b>'+ feature.properties.Owner + '</b>; ' + 
    feature.properties.Address
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius:6,
        opacity: .5,
        color:getColor(feature.properties.Contractor),
        fillColor:  getColor(feature.properties.Contractor),
        fillOpacity: 0.8
        });  
     },
```

should be:

```
    job = L.geoJson(data, {   //layer1 start
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        feature.properties.myKey = '<b>'+ feature.properties.Owner + '</b>; ' + 
    feature.properties.Address
            label = String(feature.properties.Owner)
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:6,
            opacity: .5,
            color:getColor(feature.properties.Contractor),
            fillColor:  getColor(feature.properties.Contractor),
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my- 
     labels"}).openTooltip(); 
      },
```

The `className` comes from customizing, which can be done with .css code:

```
  .leaflet-tooltip.my-labels {
   background-color: transparent;
   border: transparent;
   box-shadow: none;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 16px;
  }
```

[image]